# Query XML file for a value in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

Hi I am trying to query below Displayname in XML file using powershell

```html
<DeploymentConfiguration PackageId="dce78f0d-d8d4-4a89-9f5d-c37fbf95ee7a" DisplayName="Beyond-Compare-3-3-8" IgnorableNamespaces="" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appv/2010/deploymentconfiguration">
```

I did try

```
$Xml = Select-Xml -Path "C:\temp\Beyond-Compare-3-3-8_DeploymentConfig.xml"  -Namespace $Namespace -XPath "DisplayName="
```

I get error

> Select-Xml : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Namespace'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that
>   is not null or empty and then try the command again.
>   At line:1 char:191
>   + ... l"  -Namespace $Namespace -XPath "DisplayName="
>   +                    ~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Select-Xml], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectXmlCommand

Comment: The error means that your variable $Namespace is either null or empty

Comment: Sorry I was just editing post to include XML file I just need syntax to query what displayname value = and set to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your xml is invalid since the node does not get closed. Here is a valid version:

```
<DeploymentConfiguration PackageId="dce78f0d-d8d4-4a89-9f5d-c37fbf95ee7a" DisplayName="Beyond-Compare-3-3-8" IgnorableNamespaces="" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appv/2010/deploymentconfiguration"/>
```

Now in powershell:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-content c:\path\xmlFile.xml
$DisplayName= $xml.DeploymentConfiguration.Displayname
```

Comment: 100% Works, thank you so much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same approach, you need to register prefix mapped to the default namespace URI, pass the mapping as `-Namespace` parameter, and use the registered prefix -`ns` in this example- in your XPath. The XPath expression you tried is also invalid :

```
$Namespace = @{ ns = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appv/2010/deploymentconfiguration'; };
$Xml = Select-Xml -Path "C:\temp\Beyond-Compare-3-3-8_DeploymentConfig.xml"  -Namespace $Namespace -XPath "//ns:DeploymentConfiguration/@DisplayName"
```